# How to change color of radtreeview Telerik UI WinForms selenting and selected node

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, background-color, radtreeview

By Default RadTreeView SelectedNode BackColor is orange gradient, but I ned to change color i tryed with

RadTV_Menu_Principal.SelectedNode.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;

But that send error message because SelectedNode is null, I need pre-configurate the colors.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PhG8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution, I had to create two events for my RadTreeView.

```
enter code here
    private void RadTV_Menu_Principal_NodeMouseEnter(object sender, RadTreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        ///Paint Node when begining focus
        e.Node.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
        e.Node.GradientStyle = GradientStyles.Solid;
    }

    private void RadTV_Menu_Principal_NodeMouseLeave(object sender, RadTreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        ///Return the initial color when leave focus
        e.Node.BackColor = SystemColors.Highlight;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to achieve this is to edit the theme you are using using the [Visual Style Builder](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/tools/visual-style-builder/visual-style-builder) tool.

The other approach is to use code to [override the theme values](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/telerik-presentation-framework/override-theme-settings-at-run-time).